# Is it possible to replace the toggle paddle for a light switch ? They only have white ones and I need them to be blackblack

Tags: electrical, light, smart-switch

In this diagram below, I need to replace the toggle paddle with a black one
This is a smart wifi switch but the one I want to replace is in a three gang electrical box fully populated and I do not want to replace all of them. Besides that the plate is metal (silver) and I won't be bale to find anything like that with a smart switch. The silver plate does not look  fantastic with white switches so it has to be black.
[image]

Comment: `they only have white ones` ... where would you get a black one?

Comment: don't know ... I have black switches on the main floor ...bought the house like that. Actually ...https://www.amazon.ca/Leviton-DDKIT-SE-Decora-Digital-Switch/dp/B06Y5N7M6R/ref=sr_1_52?keywords=wifi+smart+switch+black&qid=1638308470&sr=8-52

Comment: @MiniMe, I think you could try that switch cover, but if you have a smart switch like the Belkin Wemo pictured, it may not snap on properly and it will hide the indicator lights.  Also, Wemo doesn't come in colors, so you're stuck with white if you want to stick with that brand.

Comment: yeah I ordered three of them and I will have to replace the whole thing

Comment: Careful masking and some spray paint.

Answer (score 4):

### Consult the manufacturer.

Internal components of any switch are completely proprietary to the switch manufacturer.

The entire switch is also UL Listed, which means it is listed *contingent on the entire switch being made of UL-approved components*. Only the manufacturer can assure you get internal parts which comply.

### Forget it and just get a black smart switch.

Smart switches are cheap commodity items in the $30 range, so faffing around trying to find individual sub-components is just not how the modern economy works, as I imagine you have certainly noticed.  This is the age of "throwaway stuff made in foreign lands".

So most likely the manufacturer *will not work with you* on your quest.  They have an extremely well-optimized warehousing and shipping pipeline *for retail sale of whole units*.  You imagine they have a *second*, redundant supply chain for components, with its own US warehousing operation*, packaged, barcoded, etc.  *That does not exist, because it would be cost prohibitive if it did*. The cheapest way to send you a toggle is ship a whole replacement switch through the primary supply chain.

Since this is your cosmetic choice and not their mistake, you can't expect them to do it for free. So the answer is "just buy a black smart switch".

---

---

---

* Because shipping that stuff from China would take far too long.

Comment: "This is the age of "throwaway stuff made in foreign lands.""
It seems that a new age is on the horizon.
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room/20201120IPR92118/parliament-wants-to-grant-eu-consumers-a-right-to-repair

Comment: @xeeka A fine movement, but that will not solve any of the supply chain issues that make it cheaper to deliver a whole switch to the customer than just a part of one.  The human asset is the scarce commodity, as we are painfully seeing with the labor problems.